# How does pipeline and $_ work in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

1. `Get-Process|Get-Member $_`, why doesn't this work? If `$_` represents current object in pipeline, shouldn't the above output be returning members of each process object?
2. Will a cmdlet pipeline all its output objects at once to the next cmdlet or as and when there is an object available?
3. As #1 does not work, when exactly can I use `$_` variable?  The conditions under which this variable gets created will be more helpful rather than just a cmdlet example to demonstrate the use of `$_`.

Comment: please read the about_pipelines help here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: `get-help about_pipelines`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_` is an automatic variable that is available for use within the scriptblock input of certain cmdlets to represent the current item in the pipeline.

`Get-Process | Get-Member $_` doesn't work because you send the pipeline object in to `Get-Member` via the `|`, but you then don't have any way to access the internals of `Get-Member`.

You could do this:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Get-Member
}
```

You would then get a `Get-Member` output for every item in the collection of objects output by `Get-Process`, although this would be redundant as each would be the same.

Cmdlets do send the objects down the pipeline one at a time. You can see that with this example:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
   $_
   Start-Sleep 1
}
```

You can see with the added delay that the results are arriving in the `ForEach-Object` one at a time as soon as they are available.

Other places you can use the `$_` variable are in `Where-Object` and `Select-Object`. For example:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.name -like 'win*' }
```

Here the `Where-Object` cmdlet is taking each item of the pipeline and we're using `$_` to access the name property of that item to see if it's like the string `win`. If it is, then it gets sent onwards (and so comes out to the console) if it's not, `Where-Object` discards it.

You can use `$_` in a `Select-Object` when doing calculated properties. For example:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object name,@{N='WorkingSetGB';E={$_.WorkingSet / 1GB}}
```

Here we use `$_` to get at the `WorkingSet` property of each item and then convert it to a GB value by using `/ 1GB`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$_` represents the current object in the pipeline but since Get-Member takes a pipeline input you just have to pipe the result to the cmdlet:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member
```

Another example is

```
Get-Process | Export-Csv MyFile.csv
```

Here again, $_ is not needed, because Export-Csv takes pipeline input, and receives the output of Get-Process, one process at a time, through the pipeline.  There is a loop inside the implementation of Export-csv, but that need not concern you here.

You typically use `$_` when you pipe an object to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
```